# MVC2 jquery pass object from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I am trying to pass the object myclass to the view page, the issue I am facing is null object is being returned back to the controller. Any pointers ?

**Below is the code in my ascx page**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<myclass>" %>

<div class="upModel" style="display:none">
<%= Model%>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#load").click(function () {
                try {

                   $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Loadmyaction",
                            data:  $("#upModel").serialize(),  
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                            success: function(data) { 
                             alert(data); 

                             },
                            error: function(result) { alert("Error" + result); }
                        });
                }
                catch (err) {
                    alert(err.description);
                }
          });
     </script>



    **On controller, this is my method**

      public string Loadmyaction(string obj)
            {
    string str = "";
    return str;
    }
```

Here obj is getting null from the view. Why is that no data is being passed back to the controller ?

Comment: why are you not using View.bag, or viewData

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's actually hitting your method?

Your jquery should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%=Url.Action("Loadmyaction") %>",
    data: $("#upModel").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data); 
    },
    error: function(result) { 
        alert("Error" + result); 
    }
});
```

Try changing your parameter type to `myClass`, whatever it might be.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadMyAction(MyClass model)
{
    return Json("someString");
}
```

Comment: I added what you suggested , still it is returning null.

Comment: hard to say. you should post your class and your form